# TinyAVR 0-Series: Can I use pin-change sensing without entering interrupt handler?

Tags: interrupt, avr, polling, attiny

I am evaluating the ATtiny806 running at 20MHz to build a cycle-accurate Intel 4004 microprocessor emulator. (I know it will be a bit too slow, but AVRs have a huge community.)

I need to synchronize to the external, two-phase non-overlapping clocks.  These are not fast clocks (the original 4004 ran at 750kHz)
but if I spin-wait for every clock edge, I risk wasting most of my time budget.

The TinyAVR 0-series has a very nice pin-change interrupt facility that can be configured to trigger only on rising edges.
But, an interrupt routine *round-trip* is 8 cycles (3 in, 5 out).

My question is:
Can I leverage the pin-change sensing mechanism while never visiting an ISR?
(Other processor families let you poll for interruptible conditions without enabling interrupts from that peripheral). Can polling be done with a tight skip-on-bit/jump-back loop, followed by a set-bit instruction?

Answer (score 0):

#### Straightforward way

You can always just poll on the level of the GPIO pin using the single cycle skip if bit set/clear instruction on the appropriate PORT register and bit.

But as you mention, polling does burn cycles so I'm not sure exactly what you want here - either a poll (that burns cycles but has low latency) or an interrupt (that has higher latency but allows processing to continue until the condition is true).

Note that if things get really tight and you are looking for, say, power savings by sleeping between clock signal transitions then you can do tricks like having an ISR that nevers returns (saving the IRET cycles) but that requires some careful coding probably with something like a state machine.

#### INTFLAG way

Alternately, if you want to use the internal pin state machine logic and you can live without interrupts, then you can use the `INTFLAGS` flags to check for the pin change configured in the `ISC` bits of the `PINxCTRL` register. As long as global interrupts are not enabled in `SREG` then you can spin poll on the appropriate `INTFLAG` bit to check/wait for the desired condition, and then write a `1` to that bit to clear the flag.

[image]

Note that if you want to make this fast, you will probably want to map the appropriate `PORT` to a `VPORT` since the `VPORT` registers are in I/O Memory. This lets you use `SBIS` to test the `INTFLAG` bit a single cycle and `SBI` to clear the bit in a single cycle (these instructions only work on IO memory and the normal `PORT` registers are not in IO Memory).

[image]

Finally one more complication, if you need to leave the interrupts on when doing this, it is probably possible by hacking the interrupt priority registers. You'd set the pin change to be on level 0, and then make sure the interrupts you care about are level 1 or higher, and then trick the interrupt controller into thinking that there is already a level 0 running so these interrupts do not actually fire. There are also other restrictions to this strategy so avoid it if at all possible.

#### Programmable logic way

If you want to get really esoteric, it is likely possible that you could route the input value of a pin to a configurable custom logic LUT in the chip and then route the output of that module to a bit that you test using a 1-cycle bit test (maybe an unused IO Pin). To do this, you'd feedback the output of the LUT back into one of its inputs and then use the LUT to create a strobe on the edge you are looking for. This is very complex, and also since the strobe has no acknowledgement that if the signal changes when you are not looking for it (in a spin check) then it will be lost and you will have to wait for the next edge (probably fatal in your application).

Comment: I'm trying to save 2 out of the four spin-wait loops by only looking for rising clock edges.

Comment: Answer updated with general overview of how you can check for GPIO pin change conditions with a single cycle test, but note that you much (1) leave interrupts off, and (2) map your ports to virtual ports. Report back if you need more detail.

Comment: Thanks for the additional ideas. I plan to leave interrupts off. The CCL (LUT) edge detector initially piqued my attention. Alas not enough pins, and yes, missing pulses would be bad.